# Why can't iPhone 5s upgrade to iOS 13

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iphone 5s and the current released version of iOS is 13.4.1, but I am only able to update to 12.4.6

I have found compatibility lists online (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210327) and know that iPhone 5s is incompatible with iOS 13,  but I haven't found any explanations as to why.

Would someone please explain if there is a technical reason that iPhone 5s cannot upgrade to iOS 13?

Comment: Asking _why_ Apple does one thing or another is off-topic for this site according to the [on-topic FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You've already found the facts -- the rest is speculation.

Comment: The OP did not ask an opinion based question.  There is nothing about the question that should be a reason to close it. He simply asks if anyone knew of a technical reason that an iPhone 5s couldn't host ios 13. A solid question. Sure there may be many reasons but it may stem from one or two main differences.  If you don't know what theses reasons are just don't answer. Maybe someone does.  If it's a stupid reason, so be it.

Comment: Apparently  it can run iOS 13 as a jailbreak so, it seems technically feasible.  Why Apple says “no” is probably comes down to  “user experience.”   https://taig9.com/jailbreak/ios/ios-13/

Comment: Is there something you will do with this answer to make it practical? The site scope does not include why Apple does things - it’s about what we do given what Apple has done. At this point, you clearly know Apple didn’t make the code work with the hardware so an edit would be needed to bring this in scope.

Comment: Apple recently released macOS Catalina which does not run on 32 bit processors which is an example of a technical reason for not being able to upgrade to it.  I am simply asking if there is a similar reason here.  I am astounded that this question was closed, and shows a lack of inquisitiveness encouraged by @bmike the moderator.

Comment: I'm willing to reconsider the close vote. It doesn't seem to be practical, but I'll see what others think. Your comments are very good and the question would be better if it explained a bit more - but that's my opinion and it clearly could be not valid. I'll let others decide if I'm inquisitive or not. You've been on the exchange site for 4 years, so a close vote shouldn't astound you, but that's totally your experience to have and is valid whether I expect it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question verges on one of those "opinion based" questions that are officially off topic for AskDifferent.

So *why* did Apple decide to do this? There are likely a hundred reasons, many of them technical in nature that make supporting older hardware on a newer iOS release a non-starter for iOS 13. All of those reasons, coming from us, would be guesses *at best.*

Heck I have an old iPad 3 that only goes up to 9.3.5. But it still does what I need it to do, what can you do?

The answer to that is *nothing.* Apple does what Apple does and you will never find out why. And the only technical reason that matters is "because Apple decided."

Comment: Although like you mentioned there may be technical reasons similar to how macOS Catalina can not run on 32-bit processors.  I have since found that "Apple dropped support (for ios upgrades) for all devices with less than 2 GB of RAM" which includes iPhone 5S.  Do you think Apple will continue temporarily to support older iPhones by continuing to release minor versions for iOS 12?  Or do you think we will not see any more iOS 12 releases now that iOS 13 is out?

Comment: Like I said before... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @jyapx Steve is correct that this is really opinion based. Your "wasn't aware Apple is secretive" borders on troll behavior, but let's see where this goes now that it's reopened. It might end up being an awesome thread. I've often said, the only purpose of a question is to get great answers. I don't care about question quality as much as if it gets good answers.

Comment: @bmike I honestly wasn't aware of Apple's secrecy.  I got an iPhone 5s last year, and I have only started developing for it a few weeks ago.  I apologize if I offended anyone.

Comment: Nope, no offense. As long as it is grounded in genuinely trying to solve the problem or a misunderstanding, it's all good here. And as long as you are not bound and determined to trash specific companies or people, which you seem not to be, you may proceed at will!

Comment: No offense taken. There’s so much I don’t know - I love hearing and sharing that on both sides. When I can learn and when others can learn.